# How to get work time-series with AM and PM data?

Tags: geoserver, date

I read [tutorial](http://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/tutorials/imagemosaic_timeseries/imagemosaic_timeseries.html) and get all work with data like 20170526, but how to get it's work if I have AM and PM data for specifieded date?

As I understand from docs date placing and `shp` to date field, and then specifying in URL in `&time=2017-05-26` format. But as far as I know `date` do not support AM and PM dates.

Is there any solutions?

Comment: Time format supports, well, time, if you use the `-Dorg.geotools.shapefile.datetime=true` part. See http://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/tutorials/imagemosaic_timeseries/imagemosaic_timeseries.html#step-4-set-temporal-properties for temporal property examples. Also note, we do recommend a proper DB, not shapefiles.

Comment: Could you give an example how AM and PM data will look like?

Comment: There is an example, in the link I provided. Its a time.